# Перегрузка оператора вывода << в классе C++

Tags: c++

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в программе. Изучаю C++ и дошел до перегрузки операторов.
Мне нужно сделать следующее: реализовать класс Date, который будет хранить день, месяц и год, сделать инициализацию этого класса, а также перегрузкой оператора << вывести эту дату на экран в формате (1, 1, 2000).
Класс я реализовал и перегрузку тоже, но выдает ошибку и ничего не могу поделать.

P.S. Перегрузку оператора нужно реализовать в классе, не за ее пределами (если это возможно)

Сам код:
`

```
class Date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
public:
    Date(int d, int m, int y)
        : day {d}, month {m}, year {y} { }
    int getDay() { return day; }
    int getMonth() { return month; }
    int getYear() { return year; }        

    ostream &operator<<(ostream &os) {
        return os  << '(' << getDay() << '.' << getMonth()
        << '.' << getYear() << ')' << endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    Date dd {10, 10, 2010};
    cout << dd;
    return 0;
}
```

`

Ошибка:

`In function 'int main()':
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'Date')
cout << dd;
~~~~~^~~~~`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы создали оператор, который работает наоборот :)

```
dd << cout;
```

Вот как нужно - оператор должен быть свободной функцией:

```
class Date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
public:
    Date(int d, int m, int y)
        : day {d}, month {m}, year {y} { }
    int getDay()  const { return day; }
    int getMonth()const { return month; }
    int getYear() const { return year; }        

};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Date& d) {
    return os  << '(' << d.getDay() << '.' << d.getMonth()
        << '.' << d.getYear() << ')' << endl;
}



int main() {
    Date dd {10, 10, 2010};
    cout << dd << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, как можно решить эту задачу чтобы правильно выводить, не наоборот?

Comment: См. дополненный ответ

Comment: Эту перегрузку можно ли реализовать в самом классе? Не за ее пределами

Comment: Вы можете объявить его `friend` и внести в класс (см. ответ @Александр), но от этого он **НЕ** станет реализованным в классе. Это - **свободная** функция, членом класса не являющаяся. Если вы делаете оператор членом класса, то первым должен идти объект класса - проверьте сами, в вашем варианте `dd << cout` будет работать. Так же как и если вынести определения `get...` из объявления класса - они не станут свободными функциями, а останутся членами класса.

Comment: Да, как Вы описали - работает. Еще небольшой вопрос: если реализовать 2 или 3 доп. класса, то для каждого имеется ли возможность реализовать свою перегрузку << или нет?

Comment: Да конечно, для скольки угодно классов... Сигнатуры-то будут разные.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы написать, как это можно реализовать для <<

Comment: Ну точно так же - `ostream& operator<<(ostream&os, const YourClass& y) { /* Ваш вывод */;  return os; }` - просто подставляете второй, третий и какой там нужно класс, ну и соответственно пишете код вывода.

Comment: Т.е. если определить несколько таких конструкций за пределами класса, то автоматически будет выбрана подходящая из них для определенного класса?

Comment: Конечно. Будет выполнен поиск подходящего оператора, у которого вторым аргументом - нужный объект класса. (Читайте *Перегрузка функций*; оператор - это просто функция со странным именем :) - например, ее можно вызвать не как `cout<<d`, а как `operator<<(cout,dd)`).

Comment: Большущее Вам спасибо, что помогли найти ответы на интересующие вопросы)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

class Date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
public:
    Date(int d, int m, int y)
        : day {d}, month {m}, year {y} { }
    int getDay() const { return day; }
    int getMonth() const { return month; }
    int getYear() const { return year; }

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Date &_date) {
        return os  << '(' << _date.getDay() << '.' << _date.getMonth()
        << '.' << _date.getYear() << ')' << endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    Date dd {10, 10, 2010};
    cout << dd;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А зачем ему быть `friend`, если он не использует `private` члены?

Comment: @Harry, кому как нравится, можно свободной функцией, можно friend-функцией.

Comment: Просто разбрасываться `friend`ами - нездоровое занятие. Вы же этому оператору даете полный доступ ко всем внутренностям!

Comment: @Harry, в данном случае это ни на что не влияет.

Comment: Ну, во-первых, класс может быть и пересмотрен в будущем, а во-вторых, создает нехорошую привычку :)

Comment: @Harry, вполне возможно, что как раз какие-то приватные данные и было бы полезно вывести, и тогда без friend-функции не обойтись. Все это гадание на кофейной гуще, надо исходить из конкретной ситуации.

Comment: Александр, и Вам спасибо за еще один способ реализации перегрузки операторов с помощью friend

Comment: **Когда** это будет нужно, тогда и введем `friend`. Вы же не отказываетесь от `class` и не пишете везде `struct` - потому что, вполне возможно, что...

Comment: @Harry оффтоп) а почему бы и нет.  Я обычно так делаю)

Comment: @pavel Не знаю уж, каким смайликом выразить всю полноту чувств :)